# Add a tag to text that follows a specific format

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to add a span to change the text color, but only when the text follow a certain format. For example:

```
<div>
    Random text. 
    <br>
    x. I want to add a span to this line
    <br>
    Not this one.
    <br>
    x. Yes to this.
    <br>
    x. And this!
</div>
```

In this example, I want to add a `span` to the lines that start with `x.`. I can't change the format and the text is not inside "p".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSAJS/)

```
$("div").html($("div").html().replace(/x\.(.*)/g, function(a){return "<span> " +a +"</span>"}));​
```

Comment: You don't need to call the `html()` method from within the method to get the HTML, just use the supplied parameters: [Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FSAJS/1/).

Comment: And the `replace()` could be shorter: [`replace(/(x\..*)/g, '<span>$1</span>')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FSAJS/3/). (sorry, I feel like I'm being undeservedly critical, now.) =(

Comment: Too bad this overload of jQuery.html() is not very well documented, but it sure rocks !

Comment: @mrlucmorin: it's sort of implicit, most jQuery methods have two available parameters, the first is `i` which returns the `index` of the current element within the set, and the second is effectively the property you're iterating over, so in this case it's the `html`; in the `text(function(i,t) {...})` it's the current text of the current element, and so on. So it may not be well-documented, but it's usually fairly obvious once you get the hang of it. And, if all else fails, just `methodName(function(a,b,c) { console.log(a,b,c); });` will make it pretty clear what's available. =)

Comment: @David, Thanks for pointing this out. Precious information :-)